# Capacitor polarity confusion in a circuit

Tags: capacitor, polarity

I was reading about opamp integrator concept in a text as such:

[image]

I marked the terminals of caps as **a** and **b**.
Above formula assumes the **b** terminal as being the positive end I guess.

But regarding the direction of I2, can't we say that the positive terminal of the capacitor is **a**?

But then if it the positive terminal is **a**, then it is connected to the ground. What is the + and - ends of the capacitors in the above figure?

I know it is basic circuit theory but somehow I'm confused at this point.

Isn't there only one option of the polarity of a cap at a moment for a given current direction across it?

**EDIT:**

Besides these, I also do not get why in sim for the inverting input (point X) the voltage is not zero for 10 secs of time duration.
According to op amp theory Vx must be around zero but it is around 1V here:

[image]

Comment: The simulation shows you the steady-state response.  Op-amp is in negative saturation. In transient options, you need to check this box "Skip initial operating point solution". And for R1 = 1k and Vin = 1V the capacitor (1uF) will charge to -12V in \$ T= 1\mu F *\frac{12V}{1mA} = 12ms = 0.012s \$,

Comment: But whatever the response type is, isn't it violating one of the opamp golden rules which is Vx = V- = V+ = GND in this case?

Comment: Could you write this to your answer in a detailed way? i thought "Skip initial operating point solution" would skipping something but in this case it reveals something.

Comment: No, when the opamp output is in saturation (positive or negative) this "golden rule" do not hold anymore.  Because the opamp output voltage cannot be large than supply voltage.

Comment: Try read this https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/archive/2012/05/08/op-amp-voltage-ranges-input-and-output-clearing-some-confusion

Comment: I see after a certain amount of time the cap fully charges and acts as an open i.e. infinite resistor which makes the gain infinite and saturates the opamp. In this case to see this integration one should observe the duration before the cap charges fully. But what I dont get is "Skip initial operating point" should not skip this when it is unchecked but in this case when it is checked it shows the initial part instead of skipping.

Comment: All simulation program before they start to preform the transient analysis they first calculate a DC operating point using the DC equivalent circuit, the capacitors are treated as an open circuit and the inductor as an short circuit.  And this why you see Vx = 1V and Vout = -12V. And instead of "skip inital..." you should use .IC directive.

Comment: Ctrl-RightClick on the capacitor. In the SpiceLine cell, type "IC=0", for example, to set its initial voltage to 0V.

Comment: I see I didnt know these I will try to work on this Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture is worth a thousand words

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Logically interpret it as non-polar but practically when chooosing a part Vin- = Vin+=0V so if an e-cap (polar) was used on a single supply, it's + polarity would be on the output.

Some old drafting std's use this symbol for all caps polar or not so dont be confused.  A polarized cap in America shud have the + symbol. EU , ISO and IPC stds may be different.  ( I foget which is most current std but your location, company and mileage may vary)

This academic question just shows it backwards to conventional symbols.

Comment: If lets say Vi is positive constant DC, then to me "a"(also the GND) is more positive than "b" for I2 to flow that direction for the capacitor C. So to me Vo must be negative value if Vi is positive. But the integration in the book for the Vo looks positive? Do you think I2 should be negative in that integration?

Comment: Yes for +V1, Vo=-ve and Io=- and Io=-I1 at all times until saturated output. So the formula remains correct polarity, for cap. As you can see it is always an inverting integrator, so Vo = - integral of Vin